# How can remove space between content in the index lines with sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I am trying to build content page but I see extra space in every index  , How can I get rid of space in between contents.

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   quick
   OpenAIA
   NCM6B
   IO-NCM

quick.rst
Getting Started
===============
Introduction
-------------
Prerequisites
-------------


$ pip list | grep -i "sphinx"
readthedocs-sphinx-ext 2.2.3
Sphinx 7.2.6
sphinx-rtd-theme 2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp 1.0.7
python version python3.9 -m sphinx -T -E -b html -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . test
```

[image]

Comment: Add a custom style in a custom style sheet.